How do I properly add boost to my project?
I'm working on a project for Nintendo Switch and I want to use Boost because it's required in one of the libraries I'm using.
Here's my Makefile:
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.SUFFIXES:
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ifeq ($(strip $(DEVKITPRO)),)
$(error "Please set DEVKITPRO in your environment. export DEVKITPRO=<path to>/devkitpro")
endif

TOPDIR ?= $(CURDIR)
include $(DEVKITPRO)/libnx/switch_rules

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TARGET is the name of the output
# BUILD is the directory where object files & intermediate files will be placed
# SOURCES is a list of directories containing source code
# DATA is a list of directories containing data files
# INCLUDES is a list of directories containing header files
# EXEFS_SRC is the optional input directory containing data copied into exefs, if anything this normally should only contain "main.npdm".
# ROMFS is the directory containing data to be added to RomFS, relative to the Makefile (Optional)
#
# NO_ICON: if set to anything, do not use icon.
# NO_NACP: if set to anything, no .nacp file is generated.
# APP_TITLE is the name of the app stored in the .nacp file (Optional)
# APP_AUTHOR is the author of the app stored in the .nacp file (Optional)
# APP_VERSION is the version of the app stored in the .nacp file (Optional)
# APP_TITLEID is the titleID of the app stored in the .nacp file (Optional)
# ICON is the filename of the icon (.jpg), relative to the project folder.
#   If not set, it attempts to use one of the following (in this order):
#     - <Project name>.jpg
#     - lavender.jpg
#     - <libnx folder>/default_icon.jpg
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERSION_MAJOR := 0
VERSION_MINOR := 1
VERSION_MICRO := 0

APP_TITLE   :=  lavender
APP_AUTHOR  :=  i0x0
APP_VERSION :=  ${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_MICRO}

TARGET      :=  $(subst $e ,_,$(notdir $(APP_TITLE)))
OUTDIR      :=  out
BUILD       :=  build
SOURCES     :=  source
DATA        :=  data
INCLUDES    :=  include
EXEFS_SRC   :=  exefs_src

ROMFS               :=  resources
BOREALIS_RESOURCES  :=  romfs:/

#------------------------------------
# borealis includes
#------------------------------------

SOURCES     +=  include/external/borealis/library/lib \
                include/external/borealis/library/lib/extern \
                include/external/borealis/library/lib/extern/glad \
                include/external/borealis/library/lib/extern/nanovg \
                include/external/borealis/library/lib/extern/libretro-common/compat \
                include/external/borealis/library/lib/extern/libretro-common/encodings \
                include/external/borealis/library/lib/extern/libretro-common/features \
                include/external/borealis/library/lib/extern/nxfmtwrapper

INCLUDES    +=  include/external/borealis/library/include \
                include/external/borealis/library/lib/extern/fmt/include \
                include/external/borealis/library/include/borealis/extern

#--------------------------------------
# ubitcoin
#--------------------------------------


#SOURCES    +=  include/external/uBitcoin/src \
#               include/external/uBitcoin/src/utility/ \
#               include/external/uBitcoin/src/utility/trezor

#INCLUDES   +=  include/external/uBitcoin/src \
#               include/external/uBitcoin/src/utility/ \
#               include/external/uBitcoin/src/utility/trezor

#------------------------------------------
#WALLET_CORE := include/external/wallet-core

SOURCES     += include/external/wallet-core/include \
               include/external/wallet-core/src \
               include/external/wallet-core/build/local/include \
                 include/external/boost/algorithm \
                 include/external/boost



INCLUDES    += include/external/wallet-core/include \
               include/external/wallet-core/src \
               include/external/wallet-core/build/local/include \
               include/external/boost \
                 include/external/boost/algorithm

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# options for code generation
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ARCH    :=  -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57 -mtp=soft -fPIE

CFLAGS  :=  -g -Wall -O3 -ffunction-sections \
            $(ARCH) $(DEFINES) \
            -DVERSION_MAJOR=${VERSION_MAJOR} \
            -DVERSION_MINOR=${VERSION_MINOR} \
            -DVERSION_MICRO=${VERSION_MICRO}

CFLAGS  +=  $(INCLUDE) -D__SWITCH__  \
            -DBOREALIS_RESOURCES="\"$(BOREALIS_RESOURCES)\"" \
            -DAPP_VERSION="\"$(APP_VERSION)\""

CXXFLAGS    := $(CFLAGS) -std=c++17 -DUSE_STDONLY

ASFLAGS :=  -g $(ARCH)
LDFLAGS =   -specs=$(DEVKITPRO)/libnx/switch.specs -g $(ARCH) -Wl,-no-as-needed,-Map,$(notdir $*.map)

LIBS    := -lglfw3 -lcurl -lEGL -lglapi -ldrm_nouveau -lz -lnx -lm

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# list of directories containing libraries, this must be the top level containing
# include and lib
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIBDIRS := $(PORTLIBS) $(LIBNX)


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# no real need to edit anything past this point unless you need to add additional
# rules for different file extensions
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ifneq ($(BUILD),$(notdir $(CURDIR)))
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export OUTPUT   :=  $(CURDIR)/$(OUTDIR)/$(TARGET)
export TOPDIR   :=  $(CURDIR)

export VPATH    :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(CURDIR)/$(dir)) \
            $(foreach dir,$(DATA),$(CURDIR)/$(dir))

export DEPSDIR  :=  $(CURDIR)/$(BUILD)

CFILES      :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c)))
CPPFILES    :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp)))
SFILES      :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.s)))
BINFILES    :=  $(foreach dir,$(DATA),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.*)))

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# use CXX for linking C++ projects, CC for standard C
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ifeq ($(strip $(CPPFILES)),)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    export LD   :=  $(CC)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
else
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    export LD   :=  $(CXX)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
endif
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export OFILES_BIN   :=  $(addsuffix .o,$(BINFILES))
export OFILES_SRC   :=  $(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o) $(CFILES:.c=.o) $(SFILES:.s=.o)
export OFILES   :=  $(OFILES_BIN) $(OFILES_SRC)
export HFILES_BIN   :=  $(addsuffix .h,$(subst .,_,$(BINFILES)))

export INCLUDE  :=  $(foreach dir,$(INCLUDES),-I$(CURDIR)/$(dir)) \
            $(foreach dir,$(LIBDIRS),-I$(dir)/include) \
            -Iinclude/external/boost \
            -I$(CURDIR)/$(BUILD)

export LIBPATHS :=  $(foreach dir,$(LIBDIRS),-L$(dir)/lib)

export BUILD_EXEFS_SRC := $(TOPDIR)/$(EXEFS_SRC)

ifeq ($(strip $(ICON)),)
    icons := $(wildcard *.jpg)
    ifneq (,$(findstring $(TARGET).jpg,$(icons)))
        export APP_ICON := $(TOPDIR)/$(TARGET).jpg
    else
        ifneq (,$(findstring icon.jpg,$(icons)))
            export APP_ICON := $(TOPDIR)/icon.jpg
        endif
    endif
else
    export APP_ICON := $(TOPDIR)/$(ICON)
endif

ifeq ($(strip $(NO_ICON)),)
    export NROFLAGS += --icon=$(APP_ICON)
endif

ifeq ($(strip $(NO_NACP)),)
    export NROFLAGS += --nacp=$(CURDIR)/$(OUTDIR)/$(TARGET).nacp
endif

ifneq ($(APP_TITLEID),)
    export NACPFLAGS += --titleid=$(APP_TITLEID)
endif

ifneq ($(ROMFS),)
    export NROFLAGS += --romfsdir=$(CURDIR)/$(ROMFS)
endif

.PHONY: $(BUILD) clean all

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
all: $(BUILD)

$(BUILD):
    @[ -d $@ ] || mkdir -p $@ $(BUILD) $(OUTDIR)
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(BUILD) -f $(CURDIR)/Makefile

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
clean:
    @echo clean ...
    @rm -fr $(BUILD) $(OUTDIR)


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
else
.PHONY: all

DEPENDS :=  $(OFILES:.o=.d)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# main targets
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
all :   $(OUTPUT).pfs0 $(OUTPUT).nro

$(OUTPUT).pfs0  :   $(OUTPUT).nso

$(OUTPUT).nso   :   $(OUTPUT).elf

ifeq ($(strip $(NO_NACP)),)
$(OUTPUT).nro   :   $(OUTPUT).elf $(OUTPUT).nacp
else
$(OUTPUT).nro   :   $(OUTPUT).elf
endif

$(OUTPUT).elf   :   $(OFILES)

$(OFILES_SRC)   : $(HFILES_BIN)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# you need a rule like this for each extension you use as binary data
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%.bin.o :   %.bin
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    @$(bin2o)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%.nxfnt.o   :   %.nxfnt
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    @$(bin2o)

-include $(DEPENDS)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
endif
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


My file structure
source/
resources/
include/external
 - boost/
 - wallet-core/

And how I import it in one of my files
...
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
...

But when I run make, I get this error
/home/i0x0/storage/code/lavender/include/external/wallet-core/src/Base64.cpp:9:10: fatal error: boost/algorithm/string.hpp: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

:/

"No such file or directory" - what have you done to investigate this?

literally double checked everything including my makefile and redownloading boost and copying it in my external folder

Does include/external/boost/algorithm/string.hpp exist? And if it does do you add include/external as an include folder in the Makefile?

yup, downloaded boost straight from the website and didnt remove anything from it

I think the problem is you don't have a include/external/boost/boost folder. However that is just a guess since I can't see your file systetem.

Kind of sounds like your project is not setup to look in include/external for #include's that use <>. Do you have any other source files that refer to headers under include/external, and do they work ok?

You have 2 include dirs I see that mention boost: include/external/boost and include/external/boost/algorithm I don't think either of them are being used in this case because I don't think you have include/external/boost/boost/algorithm/string.hpp or include/external/boost/algorithm/boost/algorithm/string.hpp

apparently making boost/boost worked...

I say you should have added include/external as an include path instead.

That's completely the wrong solution. -Iinclude/external not -Iinclude/external/boost
